# Could a gas go directly to a solid without becoming a liquid?

Tags: thermodynamics, phase-transition, phase-diagram

If water vapor is pulled inwards and cooled at a fast enough rate could if be frozen back into a solid form? i understand that they would have to be froze together as soon as contact is made but if this is possible what would the temperature have to be? And could this be the only thing that can directly go from a gas to a solid?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sublimation_(phase_transition)

Comment: thank you, but i don't usually refer to Wikipedia ;)

Comment: Since it seems you have a practical reason for asking, not just out of curiosity, I won't post this as an answer, but note that in the interstellar medium, everything heavier than hydrogen and helium ("metals") tends to deplete directly from a gaseous phase to a solid phase (dust grains), if the temperature is low enough and the density is high enough. Roughly 1/3 of the metals are locked up in dust this way in the ISM.

Comment: @NathanielBarnhill It's wise to use healthy skepticism when considering Wikipedia in general, but frankly, that page is likely better sourced and more complete than any answer you'll get here.  (no offense to any answer here...it's just that a short/quick q&a site is a different entity than a Wikipedia page)

Comment: @NathanielBarnhill you should start doing that then.

Comment: I think there's a meaningful discussion to be had about the other variable which is pressure. I would research the "Triple point" for the materials you're considering. This is effectively the temperature/pressure conditions where liquid, solid and gaseous phases (nearly) exist simultaneously.

Comment: @NathanielBarnhill it's not a terrible answer (the Wiki reference).

Comment: Part of our expectation for [the level of research you should undertake before asking a question](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5778) is that you should look up relevant topics on Wikipedia, as well as performing a Google search which in this case would probably turn up [a relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposition_%28phase_transition%29). If you don't trust the Wikipedia result you find, that's fine, but you do need to _find_ it and explain in the question why you don't consider it to provide a valid answer.

Comment: If you live in a cold winter climate, you should have seen frost on your windows.

Comment: dry ice (solid CO2) at atmospheric pressure is probably the most widely known example of the reverse process (sublimation)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Changing a substance from its physical state of a gas to the physical state of a solid requires the removal of thermal energy. A gas has particles that have larger amount of kinetic or moving energy, they are vibrating very rapidly. A solid has particles with lower amounts of kinetic energy and they are vibrating slower without changing position. This change of state from a gas to a solid is not a very common phase change but is referred to as deposition. It is called [deposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposition_(phase_transition)) because the particles in the gas form are depositing into a solid form.

Examples of Gas to Solid:

1. Making dry ice or solid carbon dioxide involves the removal of gaseous carbon dioxide from air and using cold temperatures and higher pressure causes the gas particles to skip the liquid phase and deposit into a solid to form a chunk of dry ice.
2. A carbon dioxide fire extinguisher has been filled with gaseous carbon dioxide but inside the canister the higher pressure causes this to turn into solid carbon dioxide which later is released as a white powder when putting out a fire.
3. In severely cold temperatures frost will form on windows because the water vapor in the air comes into contact with a window and immediately forms ice without ever forming liquid water.
4. Deposition has become a manufacturing technology application where solid alloys are heated to a gaseous state and then sprayed onto things like semiconductors. When the spray is released onto the semiconductor the heat energy is lost and the gaseous substance becomes a solid metal alloy.

Comment: So in other words it can but what about other things we usually find in gas form, like nitrogen and hydrogen, can they be put directly into solid form? hydrogen's freezing point is  -434.5°F if that is doubled would it freeze up immediately?( when its in a concentrated area)

Comment: No, it doesn't always occur like that. Both temperature and pressure have to be ideal. **The conditions for deposition vary from gas to gas.** I don't know whether someone has tried out what you said, but I've never heard about it.

Comment: Actually i'm working with a decent budget for this as a personal project for myself to see if i can find a way to change certain gases directly to a solid, i know that somewhere there is a liquid state but my goal is to make that state as quick as possible, meaning that water vapor for example would have to been under sever pressure  to let it freeze together. :)

Comment: In that case, it's difficult to provide the exact conditions, because I'm not experimenting with deposition of gases. Moreover, this site is not for such cases, and helping in experiments is off topic here. You can come over to [Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com) and ask there, and someone may help you out.

Comment: Thank you, i will post this there soon to see if i can receive any more information!

Comment: Thermal evaporation of metals (PVD) could be considered such a transition, too. The solid collected upon sublimation (for purification purposes, iodune for instance) is another example. You could add that to your answer (which I upvoted as it is).

Comment: @Alchimista [Here](http://www.semicore.com/news/71-thin-film-deposition-thermal-evaporation) it says: `in most instances of Thermal Evaporation processes the material is heated to its melting point and is liquid`.

Comment: Nitpick:  a [dry powder fire extinguisher](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uAaalWAUOZI) is different from a [$\mathrm{CO}_2$ fire extinguisher.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPhbJ95VGe0) In particular, a $\mathrm{CO}_2$ extinguisher doesn't leave any powder behind.

Comment: @WrichikBasu There are many different types of PVD of which thermal evaporation is only one. Electron-beam evaporation and laser deposition are examples of sublimation. Sputtering goes from a solid to a plasma.

Comment: "hydrogen's freezing point is -434.5°F if that is doubled" What do you mean? Are you asking what would happen to hydrogen gas if it were exposed to -869 F? That's impossible.

Comment: @user71659 In electron-beam evaporation you certainly do melt the material before evaporating it (unless using a material that sublimes at the pressure you are working at such as chrome). I'm not sure I agree that sputtered materials are a plasma. You certainly use a plasma, but don't the sputtered atoms leave the source, and stay, as neutrals? If not, they would never make it to your substrate, no?

Comment: @NathanielBarnhill If you want to avoid the liquid phase then generally you want _low_ pressure. There may also be strategies involving very high pressure (and temperature), depending on the substance, but the risk there is that the high temperature will cause the substance to decompose, or to undergo some chemical reaction with whatever gases it's exposed to (unless those gases are inert).

Comment: true, i believe that i should probably experiment with both high and low pressure environments to get a good eye on things.

Answer (score 15):

Yes.  The [Phase Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_diagram) of a substance shows when that substance is in which state.  Here is a phase diagram of water ([source](http://www1.lsbu.ac.uk/water/water_phase_diagram.html#intr2)):

[image: Phase Diagram of Water]

You can see that there are phase boundaries between each pair of states.  Where all three states meet is the [Triple Point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_point).  The boundary where solid and gas (vapor) are adjacent is generally below the triple point in both temperature and pressure; for water it starts at the familiar freezing temperature, but at less than 1% of standard atmospheric pressure.  If you want to get water to [desublimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deposition_(phase_transition)), you'll have to do it in near-vacuum.

Comment: Shouldn't it be enough that the _partial_ pressure of water in the air is below the triple-point pressure? Then you can cool it down past 0 °C without the water condensing out, and if you cool the air down even further it will already be too cold for liquid water to exist even at atmospheric pressure, so it will have to deposit directly as ice instead.

Comment: I was thinking of an isolated pure substance, not a mixture, so I didn't consider that.  Unfortunately I don't remember enough on the subject to be sure, and my search didn't yield a direct answer.  It sounds plausible - and might be testable in an ordinary freezer.

Answer (score 6):

It's called deposition.  It occurs fairly frequently with water vapor, resulting in snow (rather than hail which usually results from freezing liquid water) or frost.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to go from the solid state to a liquid/vapor state. What I mean by liquid/vapor state is that there is a certain point called the *critical point* at which liquid and vapor are indistinguishable.

The critical point you are interested in is the end of the liquid-vapor equilibrium curve on which under strictly defined circumstances the phases coexist without any flows. To do that you need to have very high pressure and then heat up the solid as shown in this graph: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/34/Phase-diag2.svg/530px-Phase-diag2.svg.png

Comment: OK so a lot of pressure would be required to turn from the gas to a solid but either way there is always going to be a liquid state no matter how fast it can be transformed?

Comment: No. Not always. after the critical point on the graph you can see an area called supercritical fluid. In this area weird stuff happen: you won't be able to tell the difference between water and vapor because the properties of water change towards those of vapor and vice-versa. For example, water is incompressible with high dielectric constant and low thermal expansion coefficient. After the critical point the water becomes compressable with high thermal expansion coefficient (like vapor).

Comment: According to the phase diagram you provided, all you need to do is lower the pressure and temperature to get a gas-solid phase transition.  Any pressure below the triple point (on that diagram) has a temperature at which sublimation/deposition will occur.